# XPath composition in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

I two XPaths, `f(x)` and `g(y)`, and some XML `x`.

```
x = <example>
  <a>
    <number>1</number>
  </a>
  <b>
    <letter>A</letter>
  </b>
  <c>
    <number>2</number>
  </c>
</example>
```

`f(x) = /example/*`

`g(y) = /number|/letter`

How do I write `h(x)` in XQuery such that `h(x) = g(f(x))` for any `g(x)`? I don't know `g(x)` ahead of time so I cannot modify it. I can modify `f(x)` if necessary. All of this needs to happen in XQuery because it's part of an Oracle query.

`h(x) = g(f(x)) = $data/example/*...`?

Comment: "All of this needs to happen in XQuery" is not entirely accurate. The XQuery is produced through some hacky string concatenation code, so I can do whatever string manipulation I want to create the query. I mean that I can't do something like grab a set of matching nodes and then apply `f(x)` to every node in that set(unless I can do it in Oracle SQL but the performance is probably less than ideal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be confused about the question, but if I have understood it correctly then the answer is

```
let $f := FFFF return $f/(GGGG)
```

where FFFF and GGGG are the expressions corresponding to f(x) and g(y)

But I'm assuming that you got your example wrong, and when you wrote

```
g(y) = /number|/letter
```

you meant

```
g(y) = number|letter
```

i.e. a relative selection rather than an absolute selection.

Comment: Yes and no on the relative selection. The result is supposed to be relative to the result of f, but most XPaths for g were written as if the result of f is the root element. The let thing may work.

Comment: That `$f/...` is similar to what started this. It seems like all the problems I'm running into are either bugs in Oracle's XQuery, bugs in Microsoft's XPath, or poorly written code that's become an integral part of the application and can't easily be changed. Unfortunately, this will probably be fixed by dumb string splitting and concatenation due to limitations imposed by legacy code. I'll accept this answer because it does work if I run it in mxquery.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to concatenate the strings:

```
h(x, g_postfix) = '$data/example/*' + g_postfix
```

Obviously taking care of '|' which would require splitting, concatenating and then joining.

Another way would be to pass the name of the "g" function and then create dynamic SQL to execute it in a loop over the node list that's returend by f().

Comment: Splitting and concatenating works for `a|b`, but `"c/(a|b)"` becomes `$data/c/(a|$data/b)` when `$data/c/(a|b)` would have been correct.

Comment: String manipulation is definitely a less reliable way. Instead, pass the function name as a string and do the dynamic SQL loop.